# How can I reopen my source in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

If I wrote a program in JAVA in Eclipse, and I start a new, I can't open it for re-writing, and compiling. I can open them with Open file... but only the .src file, and not the full program. How can I do it?

Comment: Java source files have .java extension. What files are you trying to open?

Comment: Ok, sorry, it is main, and in the file src. Sorry. I want to open the full project, because, if I only open the .java files, I can't compile and run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To edit/compile/execute a Java program in Eclipse, you need to create a project. Then add your .java file(s) to it.

Comment: But I made a project yet, but I can't re-open it if I delete it from Eclipse. Or you mean that I everytime need to make a new project, when I want to open my exist projects? :(

Comment: @user590898: What did you delete? You need your .project file, .classpath file and, if I'm not mistaken, .settings folder so that Eclipse can open your project. You would also need your project under an Eclipse workspace.

Comment: So, If I made a project, and I removed it from the workspace. Then I created a new project. But I need to edit the first project. I can't open the "full" program with Eclipse, only the .java files, or the .setting, .project, .classpath. But I can only open them separately, and I don't know how I can open the project, and not only the files.

Comment: I believe you have to create a new project and add your files there. Why do you insist on deleting the Eclipse files? Or did you just delete them without thinking and trying to salvage your application?

Comment: I made what I needed :)

 I thought it:
      File -> Import... -> General -> Existing Projects into Workspace.
   
Thanks.